# An issue with $\infty \cdot 0$ in showing that Cartesian product of a set with a null set has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, proof-verification

Here is the problem:

> Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. Furthermore $A\in \mathcal A$ and $N\in \mathcal B$ such that $\nu(N)=0$. Let $\rho:=\mu \times\nu$. Show that $\rho(A\times N)=0$.

I saw one proof where the continuity of measures is used. Yet I'd like to know if the following proof is okay or not.

Since the measure spaces are $\sigma$-finite, there exists a unique measure $\rho:\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B \to [0,\infty]$ such that for all $E \in \mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$ holds $$\rho(E)=\iint \mathbf 1_E(x,y) \ d\mu(x) \ d\nu(y)=\iint \mathbf 1_E(x,y) \ d\nu(y) \ d\mu(x) $$

Can we then write the following?
\begin{align*} 
\rho(A\times N) & = \iint \mathbf 1_{A\times N}(x,y) \ d\nu(y) \ d\mu(x) 
 \\ & =  \iint \mathbf 1_A(x) \mathbf 1_N(y) \ d\nu(y) \ d\mu(x) 
 \\ & = \int \mathbf 1_A(x) \underbrace{\int \mathbf 1_N(y) \ d\nu(y)}_{=\nu(N)=0} \ d\mu(x) 
 \\ & = \int 0 \ d\mu(x)
 \\ & = 0
\end{align*}

My problem is that it feels like $\infty \cdot 0$, since if we had $\mu(A)=\infty$ we could do the same thing as above to show that $$\infty \cdot 0 = \mu(A) \nu(N) = \cdots =0$$

Comment: In measure theory on has the convention that $0 \cdot  \infty=0$. This is exactly to ensure $\int 0 \ d\mu = 0$. Just let $X,Y=\mathbb{R}^n$ to see why this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We simply have $\rho(A \times N) = \mu(A) \cdot \nu(N) = \mu(A) \cdot 0 = 0$. In measure theory, one uses the convention $\infty \cdot 0 = 0$ because it is consistent with many formulas.

Comment: Would a reference to a convention suffice as a proof? And I guess you meant $\rho(A \times N) = \mu(A) \cdot \nu(N)$.

Comment: @LeoSchmidt Rudin says this explicitly in Real and Complex Analysis.